# Angular 2 Ace admin theme is not working as expected?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I followed the instructions as shown in this 
https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/styling
But i'm not able to get the expected output.
I've attached the plunker link of it. What changes needed to be added to make this work ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/azLsD1?p=preview

I have added

```
<tree-root 
  [ngClass]="expand-tree"
  [nodes]="nodes"
  [options]="options"
></tree-root>
```

and added expand-tree class to all the classes in my style

Thanks in advance